# Loading many images and running out of memory when using NativeJpg

Tags: multithreading, image, delphi, memory-management, delphi-xe2

I'm building a Picture Loader which has two major abilities: 1) Loading pictures in a thread, and 2) Saving cached images. Since I implemented [NativeJpg 1.32](http://www.simdesign.nl/nativejpg.html), I have been noticing that a `TsdJpgGraphic` uses approximately 3 times as much memory as the `TJpegImage`. I'm not concerned about resolving how much it reserves, but rather to make sure my threads manage the memory properly.

**Specifications**

`TPictureLoader` is the main component for this system. Every time a picture needs to be loaded, a thread is spawned to acquire that image. When the image is available, an event is triggered providing this image in the form of a `TBitmap`. Component has a queue, and a limitation of how many threads can be active at once (via `ActiveThreads` property). Every picture requested immediately creates a thread - but the thread is not executed until necessary. `ActiveThreads` determines how many of these threads can run at a time (otherwise, how many pictures can be loaded at a time).

**Problem**

`TJpegImage` always loads the pictures fine with no errors. But, using a global conditional, I enable the use of NativeJpg (`TsdJpgGraphic`) and I have memory problems. The error message is `Not enough storage is available to process this command`. This error is raised only internally (in debug), and actually does not show any error when the app is running stand-alone. It doesn't go to any breakpoint in my code, but rather in the `NativeJpg` unit on line 460: `FBitmap := SetBitmapFromIterator(AIterator);`

Using the standard `TJpegImage`, I never have problems with memory. Whether I load the picture once and then clear it from the memory, or load the picture once and save it somewhere in the memory, either way doesn't seem to make a difference. **The strange thing is that my memory just about maxes out using `TJpegImage` yet never raises any error, but when using a `TsdJpgGraphic`, the memory barely nudges at all and it already starts spitting out these errors.**

When analyzing the memory usage, I'm seeing this...

[image]

**Question**

How do I avoid this error in any situation? This system will be used in many environments, many of which will be very sluggish computers. Especially since I'm working with multithreading here, memory usage is critical.

**Source code**

```
unit PictureLoader;

interface

{$DEFINE USE_JPG}
  {$DEFINE USE_NATIVEJPG} //<---
{$DEFINE USE_PNG} 
{ $DEFINE USE_TPICTURE} 

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.StrUtils,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, SHFolder, Math
{$IFDEF USE_PNG}
  , PngImage
{$ENDIF USE_PNG}
{$IFDEF USE_JPG}
  , Vcl.Imaging.Jpeg
  {$IFDEF USE_NATIVEJPG}
  , NativeJpg
  {$ENDIF USE_NATIVEJPG}
{$ENDIF USE_JPG}   
  ;

const
  ERR_BASE =   -100;
  ERR_NOERROR =     ERR_BASE;
  ERR_UNKNOWN =     ERR_BASE - 1;
  ERR_NOFILE =      ERR_BASE - 2;
  ERR_INVALIDFILE = ERR_BASE - 3;
  ERR_UNSUPPORTED = ERR_BASE - 4;
  ERR_THREAD =      ERR_BASE - 5;

  DEF_ACTIVETHREADS =   8;
  DEF_CACHESIZE =       500;

  CACHE_DT_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yy hh:nn:ss.zzz';

type
  TPictureLoader = class;
  TPictureLoaderThread = class;

{$IFDEF USE_JPG}
  {$IFDEF USE_NATIVEJPG}
  TJpegImage = class(TsdJpegGraphic);
  {$ENDIF USE_NATIVEJPG}
{$ENDIF USE_JPG}

  TImageType = (itUnknown, itBmp
{$IFDEF USE_JPG}
    , itJpeg  
{$ENDIF USE_JPG} 
{$IFDEF USE_PNG}
    , itPng   
{$ENDIF USE_PNG}    
  );

  TActiveThreadRange = 1..99;
  TThreadMsg = (tmStart, tmReady, tmError, tmTerm);
  TCacheType = (ctNone, ctThumbs, ctOriginals, ctBoth);
  TCacheEventType = (ceError, ceGotOriginal, ceGotCached, ceGotThumb,
    ceSaveCache, ceSaveThumb);
  TCacheEvents = set of TCacheEventType;
  TImgSrc = (isOriginal, isThumbnail);
  TLoadOpt = (loNormal, loOriginal, loThumb, loCacheThumb);
  TLoadOpts = set of TLoadOpt;
  TPictureEvent = 
    procedure(Sender: TObject; Thread: TPictureLoaderThread) of object;  
  TPictureErrorEvent = 
    procedure(Sender: TObject; Thread: TPictureLoaderThread;
    var ErrCode: Integer; var ErrMsg: String) of object;                   
  TCacheEvent = 
    procedure(Sender: TObject; Thread: TPictureLoaderThread; 
    const Events: TCacheEvents) of object;

  TPictureLoader = class(TComponent)
  private
    FTimer: TTimer;
    FThreads: TList;
    FBusy: Bool;
    FLastID: Integer;
    FCacheSize: Integer;
    FCacheType: TCacheType;
    FCacheDir: String;
    FActiveThreads: TActiveThreadRange;
    FOnPictureError: TPictureErrorEvent;
    FOnPictureReady: TPictureEvent;
    FOnTerm: TPictureEvent;
    FOnStart: TPictureEvent;
    function NewID: Integer;
    procedure TimerExec(Sender: TObject);
    function NewThread(const Filename: String; 
      const Options: TLoadOpts): TPictureLoaderThread;
    procedure ThreadStart(Sender: TObject; Thread: TPictureLoaderThread);
    procedure ThreadReady(Sender: TObject; Thread: TPictureLoaderThread);
    procedure ThreadTerm(Sender: TObject; Thread: TPictureLoaderThread);
    procedure ThreadError(Sender: TObject; Thread: TPictureLoaderThread;
      var ErrCode: Integer; var ErrMsg: String);    
    procedure DoEvent(const Msg: TThreadMsg; var Thread: TPictureLoaderThread);
    procedure DoError(var Code: Integer; var Msg: String;
      var Thread: TPictureLoaderThread);    
    procedure SetLastID(const Value: Integer);
    function GetThread(Index: Integer): TPictureLoaderThread;
    procedure SetCacheDir(const Value: String);
    procedure SetCacheSize(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetActiveThreads(const Value: TActiveThreadRange);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure LoadImage(const Filename: String; const Options: TLoadOpts);
    property Threads[Index: Integer]: TPictureLoaderThread read GetThread;   
    function OriginalInCache(const Filename: String): Bool;       
    function ThumbnailInCache(const Filename: String): Bool;
  published
    property LastID: Integer read FLastID write SetLastID;
    property CacheType: TCacheType read FCacheType write FCacheType;
    property CacheDir: String read FCacheDir write SetCacheDir;
    property CacheSize: Integer read FCacheSize write SetCacheSize;
    property ActiveThreads: TActiveThreadRange
      read FActiveThreads write SetActiveThreads;    
    property OnStart: TPictureEvent read FOnStart write FOnStart;
    property OnTerm: TPictureEvent read FOnTerm write FOnTerm;
    property OnPictureReady: TPictureEvent
      read FOnPictureReady write FOnPictureReady;
    property OnPictureError: TPictureErrorEvent
      read FOnPictureError write FOnPictureError;
  end;

  TPictureLoaderThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FHasTriggered: Bool;
    FPictureReady: Bool;
    FPicture: TBitmap;
    FFilename: String;
    FID: Integer;
    FErrCode: Integer;
    FErrMsg: String;
    FMsg: TThreadMsg;   
    FActive: Bool;
    FTerminated: Bool;
    FCacheDir: String;
    FOnPictureError: TPictureErrorEvent;
    FOnPictureReady: TPictureEvent;
    FOnTerm: TPictureEvent;
    FOnStart: TPictureEvent;
    FOptions: TLoadOpts;
    FBusy: Bool;
    function GetAsBitmap: TBitmap;
    procedure CleanupThread(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SYNC_ExecMsg;
    procedure ExecuteMessage(const Msg: TThreadMsg);
    function LoadImage(const Filename: String; var Bitmap: TBitmap): Bool;
    procedure SaveImage(const Dst: TImgSrc);
    function MakeThumb(var B: TBitmap): Bool;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const AID: Integer; const AFilename, ACacheDir: String;
      const Options: TLoadOpts);
    property AsBitmap: TBitmap read GetAsBitmap;
    property ID: Integer read FID;
    property Filename: String read FFilename;
    property CacheDir: String read FCacheDir;
    property Active: Bool read FActive;
    property Options: TLoadOpts read FOptions;
    property Busy: Bool read FBusy;
  published
    property OnStart: TPictureEvent read FOnStart write FOnStart;
    property OnTerm: TPictureEvent read FOnTerm write FOnTerm;
    property OnPictureReady: TPictureEvent
      read FOnPictureReady write FOnPictureReady;
    property OnPictureError: TPictureErrorEvent
      read FOnPictureError write FOnPictureError;
  end;

function ImageType(const AFilename: String): TImageType;
function PathToFilename(const S: String; const ImgSrc: TImgSrc): String;
function FilenameToPath(const S: String): String;

implementation

//Cache Translation - Original Path to Local Filename
function PathToFilename(const S: String; const ImgSrc: TImgSrc): String;
begin
  Result:= LowerCase(S);
  if ImgSrc = isThumbnail then Result:= '_THM_' + Result;
  Result:= StringReplace(Result, '\', '_BSL_', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result:= StringReplace(Result, '/', '_FSL_', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result:= StringReplace(Result, ':', '_CLN_', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result:= StringReplace(Result, '.', '_DOT_', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result:= StringReplace(Result, '-', '_DAS_', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result:= Result + '.jpg';
end;

//Cache Translation - Local Filename to Original Path
function FilenameToPath(const S: String): String;
begin
  Result:= LowerCase(S);
  Result:= StringReplace(Result, '_THM_', '',  [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result:= StringReplace(Result, '.jpg',  '',  [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result:= StringReplace(Result, '_BSL_', '\', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result:= StringReplace(Result, '_FSL_', '/', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result:= StringReplace(Result, '_CLN_', ':', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result:= StringReplace(Result, '_DOT_', '.', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result:= StringReplace(Result, '_DAS_', '-', [rfReplaceAll]);
end;

function ImageType(const AFilename: String): TImageType;
var
  S: String;
begin
  Result:= itUnknown;
  S:= LowerCase(StringReplace(ExtractFileExt(AFilename), '.', '', [rfReplaceAll]));
  if (S = 'bmp') then begin
    Result:= itBmp;
  end else
{$IFDEF USE_JPG}
  if (S = 'jpg') or (S = 'jpeg') then begin
    Result:= itJpeg;
  end else
{$ENDIF USE_JPG}
{$IFDEF USE_PNG}
  if (S = 'png') then begin
    Result:= itPng;
  end else
{$ENDIF USE_PNG}
  begin
    Result:= itUnknown;
  end;
end;

{ TPictureLoader }

constructor TPictureLoaderThread.Create(const AID: Integer;
  const AFilename, ACacheDir: String; const Options: TLoadOpts);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate:= True;
  OnTerminate:= CleanupThread;
  FPicture:= TBitmap.Create;
  FHasTriggered:= False;
  FActive:= False;
  FID:= AID;
  FFilename:= AFilename;
  FCacheDir:= ACacheDir;
  FOptions:= Options;
  FTerminated:= False;
  FBusy:= False;
end;

procedure TPictureLoaderThread.CleanupThread(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FPicture.Free;
end;

function TPictureLoaderThread.MakeThumb(var B: TBitmap): Bool;
begin
  Result:= False;
  try

    Result:= True;
  except
    on e: exception do begin
      Result:= False;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TPictureLoaderThread.SaveImage(const Dst: TImgSrc);
var
  B: TBitmap;
  J: Vcl.Imaging.Jpeg.TJPEGImage;
begin
  J:= Vcl.Imaging.Jpeg.TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    case Dst of
      isOriginal: begin
        J.Assign(FPicture);
        J.SaveToFile(PathToFilename(FFilename, isOriginal));
      end;
      isThumbnail: begin
        B:= TBitmap.Create;
        try
          B.Assign(FPicture);
          if MakeThumb(B) then begin          
            J.Assign(B);
            J.SaveToFile(PathToFilename(FFilename, isThumbnail));
          end;
        finally
          B.Free;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    J.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TPictureLoaderThread.Execute;
var
  E: String;
begin                             
  try
    FActive:= True;
    FBusy:= True;
    FErrCode:= 0;
    FErrMsg:= '';
    ExecuteMessage(tmStart);
    if FileExists(FFilename) then begin
      if loNormal in FOptions then begin
        if FileExists(FCacheDir + PathToFilename(FFilename, isOriginal)) then begin
          if LoadImage(FCacheDir + PathToFilename(FFilename, isOriginal), FPicture) then
            ExecuteMessage(tmReady);
        end else begin
          if LoadImage(FFilename, FPicture) then
            ExecuteMessage(tmReady);
        end;
      end;
      if loOriginal in FOptions then begin
        if LoadImage(FFilename, FPicture) then
          ExecuteMessage(tmReady);
      end;
      if loThumb in FOptions then begin
        if FileExists(FCacheDir + PathToFilename(FFilename, isThumbnail)) then begin
          if LoadImage(FCacheDir + PathToFilename(FFilename, isThumbnail), FPicture) then
            ExecuteMessage(tmReady);
        end else begin
          if FileExists(FCacheDir + PathToFilename(FFilename, isOriginal)) then begin
            if LoadImage(FCacheDir + PathToFilename(FFilename, isOriginal), FPicture) then
              ExecuteMessage(tmReady);
          end else begin
            if LoadImage(FFilename, FPicture) then
              ExecuteMessage(tmReady);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end else begin
      FErrCode:= ERR_NOFILE;
      FErrMsg:= 'Original image file not found "'+FFilename+'"';
      ExecuteMessage(tmError);
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      FErrCode:= GetLastError;
      FErrMsg:= E.Message;
      ExecuteMessage(tmError);
    end;
  end;   
  while not FHasTriggered do
    Sleep(10);
  ExecuteMessage(tmTerm);
  FBusy:= False;
  FTerminated:= True;
  Terminate;
end;

procedure TPictureLoaderThread.ExecuteMessage(const Msg: TThreadMsg);
begin
  FMsg:= Msg;
  Synchronize(SYNC_ExecMsg);
  FHasTriggered:= True;
end;

function TPictureLoaderThread.GetAsBitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Result:= FPicture;
end;

procedure TPictureLoaderThread.SYNC_ExecMsg;
begin
  case FMsg of
    tmStart: begin
      if assigned(FOnStart) then FOnStart(Self, Self);
    end;
    tmReady: begin
      if assigned(FOnPictureReady) then FOnPictureReady(Self, Self);
    end;
    tmTerm: begin
      if assigned(FOnTerm) then FOnTerm(Self, Self);
    end;
    tmError: begin
      if assigned(FOnPictureError) then begin
        FOnPictureError(Self, Self, FErrCode, FErrMsg);
        if FErrCode <> 0 then begin
          raise Exception.Create(FErrMsg+' Code '+IntToStr(FErrCode));
        end;
        FErrCode:= 0;
        FErrMsg:= '';
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TPictureLoaderThread.LoadImage(const Filename: String;
  var Bitmap: TBitmap): Bool;
var
  T: TImageType;
//NOTE: If USE_JPG + USE_NATIVEJPG are defined then TJpegImage is actually TsdJpgGraphic
{$IFDEF USE_JPG}
  J: TJpegImage;
{$ENDIF USE_JPG}
{$IFDEF USE_PNG}
  P: TPngObject;
{$ENDIF USE_PNG} 
begin
  Result:= False;
  Bitmap.Assign(nil);  
  if FileExists(Filename) then begin
    if Assigned(Bitmap) then begin
      T:= ImageType(ExtractFileExt(Filename));
      case T of
        itBmp: begin
          Bitmap.LoadFromFile(Filename); 
          if FTerminated then Exit; 
          Result:= True;
        end;
{$IFDEF USE_JPG}
        itJpeg: begin
          J:= TJpegImage.Create;
          try
            J.LoadFromFile(Filename);
            if not FTerminated then begin          
              Bitmap.Assign(J);
              Result:= True;
            end;
          finally
            J.Free;
          end;
        end;
{$ENDIF USE_JPG}
{$IFDEF USE_PNG}
        itPng: begin
          P:= TPngObject.Create;
          try
            P.LoadFromFile(Filename);
            if not FTerminated then begin
              Bitmap.Assign(P);
              Result:= True;
            end;
          finally
            P.Free;
          end;
        end;
{$ENDIF USE_PNG}
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

{ TPictureLoader }

constructor TPictureLoader.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FThreads:= TList.Create;
  FTimer:= TTimer.Create(nil);
  FTimer.Interval:= 10;
  FTimer.OnTimer:= TimerExec;
  FTimer.Enabled:= True;
  FActiveThreads:= DEF_ACTIVETHREADS;
  FCacheDir:= '';
  FCacheSize:= DEF_CACHESIZE;
  FCacheType:= ctNone;
  FBusy:= False;
end;

destructor TPictureLoader.Destroy;
var
  X: Integer;
  T: TPictureLoaderThread;
begin
  FTimer.Enabled:= False;
  FTimer.Free;
  for X := 0 to FThreads.Count - 1 do begin
    T:= TPictureLoaderThread(FThreads[X]);
    if assigned(T) then begin
      T.Terminate;
    end;
  end;
  FThreads.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TPictureLoader.DoError(var Code: Integer; var Msg: String;
  var Thread: TPictureLoaderThread);
begin
  if assigned(FOnPictureError) then begin
    FOnPictureError(Self, Thread, Code, Msg);
  end;
end;

procedure TPictureLoader.DoEvent(const Msg: TThreadMsg;
  var Thread: TPictureLoaderThread);
begin
  case Msg of
    tmStart: begin
      if assigned(FOnStart) then FOnStart(Self, Thread);
    end;
    tmReady: begin
      if assigned(FOnPictureReady) then FOnPictureReady(Self, Thread);
    end;
    tmTerm: begin
      if assigned(FOnTerm) then FOnTerm(Self, Thread);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TPictureLoader.GetThread(Index: Integer): TPictureLoaderThread;
begin
  if (Index >= 0) and (Index < FThreads.Count) then begin
    Result:= TPictureLoaderThread(FThreads[Index]);
  end else begin
    Result:= nil;
  end;
end;

function TPictureLoader.NewThread(const Filename: String; 
  const Options: TLoadOpts): TPictureLoaderThread;
begin
  Result:= TPictureLoaderThread.Create(NewID, Filename, FCacheDir, Options);
  Result.OnStart:= ThreadStart;
  Result.OnTerm:= ThreadTerm;
  Result.OnPictureReady:= ThreadReady;
  Result.OnPictureError:= ThreadError;
  FThreads.Add(Result);
end;

//  MASTER PROCEDURE TO LOAD IMAGES
procedure TPictureLoader.LoadImage(const Filename: String; 
  const Options: TLoadOpts);
var
  T: TPictureLoaderThread;         
begin        
  if FileExists(Filename) then begin  
    T:= NewThread(Filename, Options);
  end;
end;

function TPictureLoader.NewID: Integer;
begin
  //FIRST CHECK IF NEW ID EXISTS OR NOT
  Inc(FLastID);
  Result:= FLastID;
end;

procedure TPictureLoader.SetActiveThreads(const Value: TActiveThreadRange);
begin
  FActiveThreads := Value;
end;

procedure TPictureLoader.SetCacheDir(const Value: String);
begin
  FCacheDir := Value;
end;

procedure TPictureLoader.SetCacheSize(const Value: Integer);
begin
  FCacheSize := Value;
end;

procedure TPictureLoader.SetLastID(const Value: Integer);
begin
  //FIRST CHECK IF NEW ID EXISTS OR NOT
  FLastID := Value;
end;

procedure TPictureLoader.TimerExec(Sender: TObject);
var
  X: Integer;
  T: TPictureLoaderThread;
  C: Integer;
begin
  if not FBusy then begin
    FBusy:= True;
    try
      C:= 0;
      for X := 0 to FThreads.Count - 1 do begin
        T:= Threads[X];
        if Assigned(T) then begin
          if T.Active then begin
            if T.Busy then begin
              Inc(C);
            end;
          end else begin
            if not T.Terminated then begin    
              Inc(C); 
              T.Resume;
            end;
          end;
        end;
        if C >= FActiveThreads then Break;
      end;
    finally
      FBusy:= False;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TPictureLoader.OriginalInCache(const Filename: String): Bool;
begin
  Result:= FileExists(FCacheDir + PathToFilename(Filename, isOriginal));
end;

function TPictureLoader.ThumbnailInCache(const Filename: String): Bool;
begin
  Result:= FileExists(FCacheDir + PathToFilename(Filename, isThumbnail));
end;

procedure TPictureLoader.ThreadError(Sender: TObject;
  Thread: TPictureLoaderThread; var ErrCode: Integer; var ErrMsg: String);
begin
  DoError(ErrCode, ErrMsg, Thread);
end;

procedure TPictureLoader.ThreadReady(Sender: TObject;
  Thread: TPictureLoaderThread);
begin
  DoEvent(tmReady, Thread);
end;

procedure TPictureLoader.ThreadStart(Sender: TObject;
  Thread: TPictureLoaderThread);
begin
  DoEvent(tmStart, Thread);
end;

procedure TPictureLoader.ThreadTerm(Sender: TObject;
  Thread: TPictureLoaderThread);
begin
  FThreads.Delete(FThreads.IndexOf(Thread));
  DoEvent(tmTerm, Thread);
end;

end.
```

*Please pardon the fact that this system isn't in fully functional order yet.*

*Component is working enough to be able to identify this problem though.*

Comment: Why do you need so many threads? Surely the bottleneck is the disk and one thread to process images is enough. Is your thread code fine without synchronisation?

Comment: Micro-managing threads, 'If thread.active', continually creating/terminating/destroying, lack of flow-control to limit memory use, all these things are prone to 'issues'.  'TimerExec' is just, well, you should find another way to manage this requirement, eg. by queueing picture load requests to a queue, (thread-safe, blocking, producer-consumer), upon which a fixed number of threads are waiting. It sounds like a pool of TsdJpgGraphic might be a good idea as well if they take so much memory.  You have so much code that I haven't looked further at any sychro issues as mentioned by David.

Comment: I need to emphasize on this comment above: "The strange thing is that my memory just about maxes out using TJpegImage yet never raises any error, but when using a TsdJpgGraphic, the memory barely nudges at all and it already starts spitting out these errors."

Comment: @MartinJames "lack of flow-control to limit memory use" - This is precisely what I would like to know how to do. I need to know how to keep these threads from even trying to exceed memory abilities in the first place. I'm really not asking "Why", I'm asking "How".

Comment: Make sure that there never more than "n" loader threads live at once? If you just spawn threads for every bmp name you find on disk, and they all allocate some memory in startup and then block for their turn for disk I/O, you can already have a tremendous memory spike

Comment: I am limiting the number of live threads at once. `FThreads: TList` is a queue for all the threads, and they are not run immediately. `FTimer` comes along and executes them as needed. This timer never lets more than `FActiveThreads` number of threads at once. I have this error even when I have this set to 1 thread at a time. There may be for example 100 images, thus 100 threads, but only 1 of those threads will actually be alive at a time (or as specified by `FActiveThreads`).

Comment: Are you really creating one thread per image? Do you know that every thread you create reserves its stack address space. That's 1MB by default. Create a lot of threads and you will exhaust your address space. If you want 1 thread to run at once then create 1 thread. Feed it jobs with a threadsafe queue.

Comment: The end goal of this project is to be able to load more than one image at the same time. But I'm starting to realize that in order to build this how I want it, it needs to analyze the available resources. Because a developer could easily set the limit of active threads to 99 for example, and my project just assumes that it's available. I will re-think the design to wait to create the threads. But the problem still persists with the `TsdJpgGraphic`. I'm starting to doubt that it was designed assuming there may be 2 different threads loading an image at the same time.

Comment: Frankly the code is a complete and utter disaster. If I was presented with that code I would throw it in the bin and start again. There's little point simultaneously loading more images than you have disks. The disk is the bottleneck. But if you create hundreds of threads then expect to run out of memory for the reasons I just gave you.

Comment: In the environment this is designed for, all the originals are stored on the server (can take time to load). 1 picture may take for example 10 seconds to load, in any situation. I'm building this to be able to load, for example, 3 images at once - cut the time into 1/3. I'm not saving anything onto the local disk - unless the `TsdJpgGraphic` is using my HDD. PS - I just added a screenshot above.

Comment: Then the bottleneck will be the disk on the server and the network transfer. Is threading going to speed things up? Anyway, you never answered my question. Are you creating hundreds of threads?

Comment: Technically, yes, I 'create' as many threads as needed. But they're not 'executed' until needed. Is this wrong then? I definitely understand the limitations of the server + network, so it may not be exactly 1/3 of the time, it might be just 20% faster. But any bit faster is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Don't create more threads than you intend to run at once. I've already explained why not. How many are you creating. Create as many threads as you want to run simultaneously. Then feed them with a thread safe queue. The code needs a complete re-write. You should be using `AsyncCall` or `OmniThreadLibrary`. You don't know enough about threading to write your own threading code. Sorry. You just want a simple thread pool to which you feed tasks.

Comment: @David +1 At Jerry: and even if there are as many disk as the number of images, then there is the core number limit over which the threads will be distributed. Also, there is no (easy) way to tell the system to use all the available processors; it desides for itself, doesn't it?

Comment: @NGLN I'm not as worried about CPU usage as I am about memory usage. I also am very clearly understanding that there ARE better ways of doing this system, but that is subject to another question. The issue I'm trying to address is that `TsdJpgGraphic` is raising errors which `TJpegImage` does not raise on the exact same images and process of loading them.

Comment: And PS - This website is not a place to judge how good or bad of a coder someone is. It's a place to ask for help and answer people's questions for help.

Comment: Yes, Jerry. This is a place to ask questions that other people might find helpful. I'm asking you to put in some effort to ask smarter and less jumbled questions.  By referring to your code not working the way you want, as "it sucks" I am paraphrasing your actual question.

Comment: I have to thank everyone for pointing out the flaws in my coding, and appreciate the guidance to re-structure it. But regardless, we're still drifting off topic of what I'm asking, and I don't think my structure of the threading is the cause of the problem - I think the simple fact of using a thread at all is causing this error.

Comment: Or possibly - could it be that the `TsdJpgGraphic` object is attempting to 're-use' the same block of memory for storing the same data? I at least would hope not, but I'm suspecting some sort of interference between 2 instances of `TsdJpgGraphic`, both loading different pictures at the same time.

Comment: I suggest you take this question to the supplier of this `TsdJpgGraphic`. SimDesign has a [NativeJpg forum](http://www.simdesign.nl/forum/viewforum.php?f=16).

Comment: @NGLN Already on it, but at this point I still really don't know if the problem is how my threads are loading the image, if it's a bug in NativeJpg, if it's something I'm missing about threads, or what.

Comment: I would have posted my issue in the forums there by now, if my account which I registered for 2 weeks ago was activated.

Comment: By the way, all my references to `TsdJpgGraphic` are actually supposed to be `TsdJpegGraphic`. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure if this is your problem, but there is a huge design flaw with your current code. You are creating 1 thread per image. Assuming that you have hundreds or thousands of threads this design cannot scale.

For a start there is a significant overhead associated with creating, starting and terminating threads. You don't want to pay that overhead time and time again.

But more problematic is the resource overhead for a thread. Each thread has its own private stack space. The address space (1MB) for that stack is reserved (but not committed) when the thread is created. With enough threads you will exhaust your address space, even though your actual memory commit level is still low.

I strongly urge you to abandon that code and start again. You should use one of the established threading libraries. Threading is hard to do well and you need a lot of knowledge and expertise to do it well. Use either [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/) or [AsyncCall](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/).

What you are looking for is a simple thread pool with a small number of threads. You should then simply feed tasks (i.e. image file names) to the thread pool and let it manage the processing of those tasks.

Comment: +1 I'm sure all this is 100% valid and true in my scenario - and I will redesign the system again (a 3rd time actually). However I'm still concerned about the `TsdJpgGraphic` raising memory errors far before my memory is even filled. I'm willing to bet that `TsdJpgGraphic` doesn't consider the fact that there may be 2+ instances loading images at the same time as each other (one after the other, yes - but more than 1 at once, I can see some possible flaws that can freak a thread in this way).

Comment: @Jerry Read up on the difference between reserved memory and committed memory. You don't make sense when you say 2+ loading at the same time, one after the other. Those are mutually exclusive. Why do you think NativeJpg is not threadsafe. Would be astounding if it wasn't.

Comment: I know the difference. My point is there are two scenarios: 1) Load 3 pictures, one after another, or 2) Load 3 pictures at the same time. Loading the 3 at the same time is only possible by using 3 threads.

Comment: INcidentally, why a commercial closed source app that we can't examine the source code to, uses as much memory as it does is an unanswerable question....  Why ask people (when nobody here has this library) what this thing we don't know what it is does....

Comment: @WarrenP FYI, 1) NativeJpg is open-source, 2) This question does and will have an answer (there's nothing "unanswerable" about it), and 3) it was numerous people from here which directed me to this library in the first place. And I also did provide a link to where this library came from. I registered for an account for the SimDesign forums long ago, and still hasn't been activated. Otherwise, I would have gone there already.