# Multithreaded 64 bit process goes "Out of memory"

Tags: multithreading, delphi, debugging, memory

I have memory and CPU intensive application which runs several hundred concurrent threads that do text processing. There is a lot of going on in background, processing files, logging to disk, and so on. Application is compiled for x64 platform, under XE2.

Occassionaly, it crashes, and I've been trying to debug this issue for a few days, but without success. Here is the bug report: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sSUXCznT

I tried running it under debugger and it reports `Out of Memory` exception after a while. At the point of crash, it was using 670mb of RAM, and machine has 32gb total RAM.

I was thinking it may be fragmentation, but if I'm understanding this bug report correctly, it says *largest free block : 8185.75 GB*, which indicates that fragmentation isn't the issue here.

Application isn't leaking memory anywhere (atleast that I know of), I have `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` enabled and it works fine.

Since I don't have any other ideas why it would crash with `Out of memory` exception, I would like to get some hints so I can get on the right path to fix this.

Comment: The bug report is `EInvalidPointer` rather than out of memory. How can we reproduce the fault?

Comment: A bit below it says thread $17a4, inner exception level 1: >> EOutOfMemory, Out of memory. When ran under debugger, it also crashes with that message. Asking to reproduce the bug doesnt make much sense here. If I knew why it crashes, I wouldn't open this thread at the first place.

Comment: Stack trace looks odd for that thread. Without a repro I have little to offer.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I can debug it? Point is that I have no idea why it crashes and where it crashes. App is rather complex, so I can't make simple test case.

Comment: Try and make a simple test case. And set a break point on the code that raises the out of memory exception.

Comment: If it fails on ReallocMem, then you should figure out how much of memory you are trying to allocate there.

Comment: @Andrei But why would WaitForSingleObject call ReallocMem?

Comment: @David I don't think that WaitForSingleObjectEx may fail in such way. MadExcept (and all other stack loggers) is not perfect, quite often it shows strange things on the stack. I can believe that ReallocMem generates EOutOfMemory, so it should be checked first (strange things on the stack can be ignored for a while).

Comment: And it can be useful to use FastMM with additional debug features switched on (especially control of double freeing).

Comment: I haven't even read half your question yet and I advise you immediately that's far too many threads. Open the Windows task manager, make sure you show processes from all users, and enable the "Threads" column to show. Look through there and note the thread count of all running processes. The only one with over 100 is the "System" process, and even mine says just 137 (that's a virtual process anyway). The next highest is my Avast A/V, which has just 60 threads.

Comment: Even our company's 3 SQL Server instances, each with many active and commonly used databases, run thread counts of 52, 64, and 67. And that's a very "memory and CPU intensive application"

Comment: That being said, refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997978/loading-many-images-and-running-out-of-memory-when-using-nativejpg

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a breakpoint in System.pas `procedure Error(errorCode: TRuntimeError);`. Your Application should stop there when the out of memory happens. When you get there, skip the ErrorAt function (by using Debug->"Set next statement" in the context menu). That will silently ignore the exception so you can debug the call stack easier. Leave the functions with F7 until you have a useful stack trace.